# What is 4sL format in struct.pack Python

Tags: python, sockets

I am new to python and my first program is to write a code for receiving multicast packets.

I got [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) code for example and similar codes everywhere.

```
import socket
import struct

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', 4242))
mreq = struct.pack("=4sl", socket.inet_aton("224.51.105.104"), socket.INADDR_ANY)

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq) 
while True:
   print sock.recv(10240)
```

I am not able to figure out this code. especially the ***4sl*** part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [the `struct` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings).

`=` means native byte order, standard sizes, and no alignment. `4s` means "four-letter string" (four char joined together into a bytestring), `l` means "signed long", in this case a four-byte int.

As for the rest of the code, this is setting up a multicast udp listener bound to port 4242. `mreq` is this structure (C code):

```
struct ip_mreq {
    struct in_addr imr_multiaddr;   /* IP multicast address of group */
    struct in_addr imr_interface;   /* local IP address of interface */
};
```

This code stores that data in `mreq`, which is passed to `setsockopt` to inform the OS that you are interested in data from that multicast address.

A google search revealed [this tutorial](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html) on IP multicast.

Comment: `inet_aton(3)` already does the native to network byte order translation, so the `=` is correct.

Comment: Endianess is not applicable to char arrays (like Python `socket.inet_aton` return value is), only to multibyte numerical values.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Good point, and since `socket.INADDR_ANY` is zero anyway, the endianness is irrelevant.

Comment: here the person is using `mreq` as a variable. I am not getting it. what is the use of this.?

Comment: And if in case the sending side is not sending a data for 4char string and a long. it is sending a data more complex then.?

Comment: `mreq` is not being *sent*, it is used to configure the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` socket option using `setsockopt` which expects raw C data structures (byte strings).

Comment: None of this code is sending anything, it is only printing whatever is received.

Answer (score 2):

From [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) format specification:

- `=` means "use platform endianess"
- `4s` means "first thing is a string of four chars"
- `l` means "a long integer follows"

So you are packing (writing to a byte vector) four characters followed by a long integer. Endianess matters for the latter.

Comment: then that means it can only receive 4 characters and one long.?? Ryt.??

Comment: from the docs: "For packing, the string is truncated or padded with null bytes as appropriate to make it fit." So, if your string is longer than 4 chars, only the first 4 will be considered; if it is shorter, '\0' will be added. Since you are packing an IP address, you will get exactly 4 chars (bytes).